# E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: android, react-native

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

I am getting this exception after updating into react native 0.60.0. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're going past the end of an array somewhere.  Don't do that.

Comment: it may cause by flatlist bug try to set removeClippedSubviews=false on your flatlist